# Store execution result in java in properties file

Tags: java, runtime, config, execution, properties-file

I wrote a code in java to run some scripts which can return different result depending on the environment setup. I would like to store the result of every execution. I try with properties file but every time it executes, it overwrites the previous result in `config.properties`. I did a research but not find any most likely example. This is my code to return properties file. The value which will be different are `TCpassed` and `TCfailed` on every execution.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ExecutionProperties {

    public void setConfigProperties(int tcPassed, int tcFailed){
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {

            output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

            // set the properties value
            prop.setProperty("TCpassed", ""+ tcPassed);
            prop.setProperty("TCfailed", ""+ tcFailed);

            // save properties to project root folder
            prop.store(output, null);

        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Is it possible to get the execution time and store it in `config.properties` in order to differentiate with the previous result?

Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

You can use append mode using constructor `FileOutputStream("config.properties", true)`
Sample properties file after couple of execution

```
#Mon May 04 13:03:29 IST 2015
TCpassed=1
TCfailed=1
#Mon May 04 13:04:03 IST 2015
TCpassed=1
TCfailed=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Property file are usually key value pairs, e.g.

```
TCpassed=9
TCfailed=1
```

So if you want to store the result of every execution, you need a different key for every execution.
And if you want to append to the property file, you can:

1. Load the property file as Properties object;
2. Add new entry to the Properties object;
3. Write the Properties Object back to the file;

Here is an example:

```
  public static void appendTestResult(File propertyFile, int tcPassed, int tcFailed) {
        try {
            Properties properties = loadProperties(propertyFile);
            String testId = getTestID();
            properties.setProperty("TCpassed_" + testId, String.valueOf(tcPassed));
            properties.setProperty("TCfailed_" + testId, String.valueOf(tcFailed));
            saveProperties(propertyFile, properties);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void saveProperties(File propertyFile, Properties properties) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = FileUtils.openOutputStream(propertyFile);
            properties.store(outputStream, "new test");
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        }
    }

    public static Properties loadProperties(File propertyFile) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(propertyFile);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(inputStream);
            return properties;
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        }
    }

    public static String getTestID() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
    }
```